# Как запустить команду с удаленного на локальный ПК

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Я захожу на удаленный **ПК** по **ssh**

```
ssh root@sshhost
```

и на удаленном **ПК** лежит скрипт *test.sh*
я его запускаю

```
sshhost~$ sh test.sh
```

скрипт делает свое дело на sshhost  все *ок* !
но мне нужно в конце этого скрипта в файле *test.sh* написать команду которая запустит у меня на локальном **ПК** к примеру браузер, как это сделать куда капать ?

все команды из *test.sh* будут выполнятся на *sshhost*  и лишь одна последовая на локалке 
это будет выглядеть примерно так в *test.sh* `x-www-browser ${SITE_NAME}`
при этом локальный пользователь может быть разный , то есть тот кто будет запускать *test.sh*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
~$ ssh user1@remote "ssh user2@local firefox"
```

*remote* - адрес удалленного хоста, sshd должен быть запущен

*local* - адрес хоста доступный для *remote*

Если проброшены ключи тогда все будет ок, без - читайте про **expect**

*test.sh*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

home_machine=1.2.3.4

user2@"$home_machine" "firefox"
```

**UP**

Конечно, ситуация описываемая в вопросе, очень не правдоподобная, выходит следующее:

```
[local_machine] --{ssh}--> [remote_machine] --{ssh}--+
      ^                                              |
      |                                              |
      +------------------{run firefox}---------------+
```

Создавать замкнутый тоннель, когда можно запустить локально выбор не самый оптимальный, если конечно не имелось в виду проброс порта на локальную машину с удаленного хоста:

```
~$ ssh -L 9999:localhost:80 user@remotehost
```

В этом случаю сервис работающий на *remotehost*:80 и не доступен на прямую (блокирующий брандмауэр или тип запуска сервиса) будет доступен на _localhost__:9999. Это работает с учетом того, что ssh открыт на обоих машинах.

Comment: "ssh user2@local firefox"  будет запускаться в test.sh и видимо нужно записать в переменную user2 и local так как это может быть и user3 к примеру . но как это сделать ?

Comment: @skatch_mast Просто добавте user2@local firefox в скрипт

Comment: Но в том то и дело что home_machine может быть разный ip в зависимости от того кто вошёл по ssh , только как его записать туда, в принципе это уже другой вопрос

Comment: Только,  пожалуй,  этот обратный ssh лучше запускать в фоне и через `nohup` (иначе прямой не завершится)

Comment: @skatchmast ```home_machine="$(w | grep $USER | awk '{print $3}')"``` -- IP текущего пользователя на _remote_ но не факт что если использовать _user2_@_$_home_machine_  вы сможете залогинится обратно

Comment: Я об этом и говорю , нужно по факту вычислять кто подключился и его имя и ИП инициализировать в переменную

Comment: @skatchmast это не сложно, сложней выяснить есть ли этот пользователь на той машине ОТКУДА шло подключение. Если сеть заранее пред определена, т.е. известны вСе пользователи на каждом из хостов, то можно создать список и сверятся с ним. Можете открыть другой вопрос, тема интересна.

Answer (score 1):

Можно откусить запуск firefox и оставить его на локальной машине.

Локально запускаем:

```
ssh user@remote /usr/local/bin/test.sh && \
scp user@remote:/tmp/test.vars /tmp/test.vars && \
source /tmp/test.vars
firefox $SITE_NAME
```

На удаленном хосте в test.sh:

```
#делаем что нужно и записываем результаты в переменные
echo VAR1=$VAR1 > /tmp/test.vars
echo SITE_NAME=$SITE_NAME >> /tmp/test.vars
exit 0
```

Файлик с переменными скопируем локально и применим, дальше можно запустить firefox c результатом.

Если результат - это файлы - их можно также скопировать через scp.

Если результат скрипта это запуск сервера, то проброс портов через `-L` удобнее.